# Showing that a Hopf bifurcation exists?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, modeling

I have the following system of ODEs:

dx/dt = a/(1 + z) - Q*z

dy/dt = Qx - qy

dz/dt = qy - cz/(K + z).

Assuming K = 1, Q = q < c, and a = c*(Sqrt[c/Q] - 1), is there a way to use Mathematica to test whether a Hopf bifurcation exists?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: To be clear, there are two parameters left (`q` and `c`)?

Comment: @ChrisK Yes, we are missing q and c. I found that a bifurcation happens when q = c/4, but I have no idea how to test if this is a Hopf bifurcation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can use my [EcoEvo package](https://github.com/cklausme/EcoEvo), despite the fact that this doesn't seem like an ecological model.

First, install the package (only needs to be done once):

```
PacletInstall["EcoEvo", "Site" -> "http://raw.githubusercontent.com/cklausme/EcoEvo/master"]
```

Now, load the package, set the model and add your assumptions on parameters:

```
<< EcoEvo`

SetModel[{
  Aux[x] -> {Equation :> a/(1 + z) - Q z},
  Aux[y] -> {Equation :> Q x - q y},
  Aux[z] -> {Equation :> q y - c z/(k + z)}
}]

k = 1;
Q := q;
a := c (Sqrt[c/Q] - 1);
```

We can find equilibria with `SolveEcoEq`:

```
eq = SolveEcoEq[]
```

[image]

There are two.  To get an overview of where bifurcations happen in the `c`--`q` plane, plot where the maximum real part of the eigenvalues at each equilibrium equal zero:

```
λ1[c_?NumericQ, q_?NumericQ] := Max[Re[EcoEigenvalues[eq[[1]]]]];
λ2[c_?NumericQ, q_?NumericQ] := Max[Re[EcoEigenvalues[eq[[2]]]]];

ContourPlot[{λ1[c, q] == 0, λ2[c, q] == 0}, {c, -2, 2}, {q, -2, 2},
  FrameLabel -> Automatic, MaxRecursion -> 3]
```

[image]

To investigate more closely, let's take an arbitrary slice at `q = 0.2`.

```
q = 0.2;
Plot[λ1[c, q], {c, -1, 2}]
Plot[λ2[c, q], {c, -1, 2}]
```

[image]

[image]

Seems like each equilibrium has two bifurcations in this range.  We can use `FindRoot` to solve for them, eyeballing the graphs for initial guesses:

```
bif1a = FindRoot[λ1[c, q], {c, 0.19}]
bif1b = FindRoot[λ1[c, q], {c, 1.1}]
bif2a = FindRoot[λ2[c, q], {c, 0.01}]
bif2b = FindRoot[λ2[c, q], {c, 0.5}]

(* {c -> 0.2} *)
(* {c -> 1.03904} *)
(* {c -> 0.070988} *)
(* {c -> 0.466855} *)
```

Now we can evaluate the eigenvalues of the jacobian matrix at the bifurcation points to see if they're Hopf bifurcations (two complex conjugate eigenvalues with zero real part, non-zero imaginary part).

```
c = c /. bif1a;
EcoEigenvalues[eq[[1]]]
(* {-284390., -0.199832, -0.000168003} *)

c = c /. bif1b;
EcoEigenvalues[eq[[1]]]
(* {-0.42987, 0. + 0.214415 I, 0. - 0.214415 I} *)

c = c /. bif2a;
EcoEigenvalues[eq[[2]]]
(* {-0.303951, 0. + 0.144188 I, 0. - 0.144188 I} *)

c = c /. bif2b;
EcoEigenvalues[eq[[2]]]
(* {-0.358281, 0. + 0.177922 I, 0. - 0.177922 I} *)
```

Nope, yep, yep, yep!

We can simulate the dynamics for select values of `c` to make sure.

*bif2a:*

```
c = 0.05;
EcoEigenvalues[eq[[2]]]
sol = EcoSim[RuleListAdd[eq[[2]], {x -> 0.01}], 1000];
PlotDynamics[sol]
(* {-0.297406, 0.0143882 + 0.148584 I, 0.0143882 - 0.148584 I} *)
```

[image]

```
c = 0.1;
EcoEigenvalues[eq[[2]]]
sol = EcoSim[RuleListAdd[eq[[2]], {x -> 0.01}], 1000];
PlotDynamics[sol]
(* {-0.316999, -0.0155364 + 0.139724 I, -0.0155364 - 0.139724 I} *)
```

[image]

*bif2b:*

```
c = 0.45;
EcoEigenvalues[eq[[2]]]
sol = EcoSim[RuleListAdd[eq[[2]], {x -> 0.01}], 1000];
PlotDynamics[sol]
(* {-0.358413, -0.00121928 + 0.176904 I, -0.00121928 - 0.176904 I} *)
```

[image]

```
c = 0.48;
EcoEigenvalues[eq[[2]]]
sol = EcoSim[RuleListAdd[eq[[2]], {x -> 0.01}], 10000];
PlotDynamics[sol]
(* {-0.358171, 0.000917014 + 0.178671 I, 0.000917014 - 0.178671 I} *)
```

[image]

*bif1b:*

```
c = 1.0;
EcoEigenvalues[eq[[1]]]
sol = EcoSim[RuleListAdd[eq[[1]], {x -> 0.1}], 1000];
PlotDynamics[sol]
(* {-0.435545, -0.00286826 + 0.213892 I, -0.00286826 - 0.213892 I} *)
```

[image]

```
c = 1.1;
EcoEigenvalues[eq[[1]]]
sol = EcoSim[RuleListAdd[eq[[1]], {x -> 0.1}], 10000];
PlotDynamics[sol]
(* {-0.422319, 0.00401044 + 0.215014 I, 0.00401044 - 0.215014 I} *)
```

[image]

Interesting to note that at `c = 1.1` both equilibria are unstable.  If we start next to `eq[[2]]` we actually end up on a different limit cycle:

```
sol2 = EcoSim[RuleListAdd[eq[[2]], {x -> 0.1}], 10000];
PlotDynamics[sol2]
```

[image]

```
RuleListPlot[{FinalSlice[sol, 100], FinalSlice[sol2, 100]}]
```

[image]

So, there's a lot going on here.  BTW, I don't see anything special about `q = c/4`.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 7):

You will have a Hopf bifurcation if two Eigenvalues of the Jacobian at a fixpoint have pure imaginary conjugate complex values.

Therefore, we first need the equilibrium or fix points. With the parametervalues from your post we get the fixpoints:

```
rhs= {a/(1+z)- Q z, Q x- q y, q y - c z/(K+z)} //. {K->1,Q->q,a->c(Sqrt[c/Q]-1),q->c/4}

fixpt = {x, y, z} /. Solve[rhs == 0, {x, y, z}]
```

[image]

Now we can linearize the right hand sides around the fixpoints. For the first fixpoint we get:

```
lin = Series[rhs, 
   Sequence @@ Transpose[{{x, y, z}, fixpt[[1]], {1, 1, 1}}]] // 
  Normal;
```

The Jacobi matrix (all first derivatives) can be get by:

```
jm = D[lin, {{x, y, z}}];
```

And the Eigenvalues:

```
Eigenvalues[jm] // N
```

[image]

You see that we can not get 2 pure imaginary conjugate complex Eigenvalues.

For the second Eigenvalue we get:

[image]

Again 2 pure imaginary conjugate complex Eigenvalues are not possible.

Comment: So because two of the Eigenvalues have conjugate complex values, we know that the bifurcation is a Hopf bifurcation? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I remembered this wrong. The eigenvalues must be conjugate and purely imaginary. I will look at it if I have time.

Comment: I corrected my answer.

Comment: So, to be clear, there is no Hopf when q=c/4, but three Hopf when q = 0.2 -- see first answer

Answer (score 1):

I will make a guess that this system comes from an application involving positive variables and parameters. This "essential nonnegativity" is only possible if the first equation is wrong, and Q z is in fact Q x. The fixed point becomes then unique. I will ignore the assumption on a, since Mathematica can handle problems with three parameters. The essential equation for a "candidate of Hopf bif. in three dimensions" is c1 c2 ==c3, where ci are the coefficients of the Char. Pol. of the Jacobian -- see for example Routh–hurwitz-liénard–chipart criteria
SL Wiggers, P Pedersen
A short program will produce a condition on a (not the one given), from which we can get examples and test them graphically

```
xv = a/(1 + z) - q*x;
yv = q*x - q*y;
zv = q*y - c*z/(1 + z); X = {x, y, z}; par = {q, c, a}; cp = 
 Thread[par > 0];
dyn = {xv, yv, zv}; fp = Solve[Thread[dyn == 0], X][[1]]
jac = D[dyn, {X}]; jac // MatrixForm
tr = Tr@jac /. fp // FullSimplify
det = Det[jac] /. fp // FullSimplify
pol = -CharacteristicPolynomial[jac, s] /. fp // Apart
cof = CoefficientList[pol, s]
re = Reduce[Join[{cof[[1]] *cof[[2]] - cof[[3]] == 0 && q < c}, cp]]
fi = FindInstance[re, par, 3]; fi // N
```

The original question could be slightly harder, due to the two fixed points.

Answer (score 1):

The following answer is just a guide to detect the Hopf bifurcation in your system:

Considering $a=\frac{3}{8}$, $c=\frac{4}{3}$, $k=\frac{3}{2}$, $Q=\frac{1}{2}$ and $q$ as a bifurcation parameter, your system becomes as follows:

```
F[{x_, y_, z_}][q_] := {-(z/2) + 3/(8 (1 + z)), 1/2 (x - 2 q y), q y - (8 z)/(9 + 6 z)}
X = {x, y, z};
```

The nontrivial equilibrium point:

```
X0[q_] := First@SolveValues[F[X][q] == 0, X]
X0[q]
(*{2/3, 1/(3 q), 1/2}*)
```

Jacobian matrix:

```
J[{x_, y_, z_}][q_] := Evaluate[D[F[X][q], {X}]]
J[X][q]
(*{{0, 0, -(1/2) - 3/(8 (1 + z)^2)}, {1/2, -q, 0}, {0, q, (48 z)/(9 + 6 z)^2 - 8/(9 + 6 z)}}*)
```

The linear approximations at $X_{0}(q)$:

```
J0[q_] := J[X0[q]][q]
J0[q]
(*{{0, 0, -(2/3)}, {1/2, -q, 0}, {0, q, -(1/2)}}*)
```

Local stability using `BialternateSum`:

```
Reduce[Det[BialternateSum[J0[q]]] < 0 && q > 0, q]
(*q > 1/6*)
```

Looking for the Hopf bifurcation value using `BialternateSum`:

```
q0 = First@SolveValues[Det[BialternateSum[J0[q]]] == 0 && q > 0, q]
(*1/6*)
```

The eigenvalues at $q=q_0$:

```
Eigenvalues[J0[q0]]
(*{-(2/3), I/(2 Sqrt[3]), -(I/(2 Sqrt[3]))}*)
```

The limit cycle appears for $q<q_0$:

[image]

There is a condition that makes the two non-trivial equilibria collapse into one, so it is possible to study a Bogdanov-Takens bifurcation in your system.

I hope you enjoy it!